# Python Add If Statement Answers

Tags: python-3.x

I'm learning python and got stuck on the if statement. I'm trying to total the answers to the input statements if I enter Yes to all 3 questions, but instead I get YesYesYes, instead of 0.60. Code below:

```
Question_1=input("Did you look at the OCC strategy in the line chart? ")
if Question_1=="Yes":
    print (0.2)
else:
    print (0) 

Question_2=input("Are you trading in the same direction as the 20 day moving average? ")
if Question_2=="Yes":
    print (0.2)
else:
    print (0) 

Question_3=input("Are you trading in the same direction as the 50 day moving average? ")
if Question_3=="Yes":
    print(0.2)
else:
    print(0) 

Total=(Question_1 + Question_2+Question_3)
print(Total)
```

Comment: `Question_1`, `Question_2`, and `Question_3` are strings so using `+` on them results in string concatenation.

Comment: Given that `Question_1` is `"Yes"` and `Question_2` is `"Yes"` and `Question_3` is `"Yes"` (you've specifically checked for these values) it's hard to see why `"YesYesYes"` would be an unexpected output for `Question_1 + Question_2+Question_3`.

Comment: You need to store the score of each question somewhere or keep a running total. `Total = 0`. Then `if Question_1=="Yes": Total += 0.2`, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a possible solution:

```
question_1 = input("Did you look at the OCC strategy in the line chart? ")
result_1 = 0
if question_1.lower().strip()=="yes":
    result_1 = 0.2

question_2 = input("Are you trading in the same direction as the 20 day moving average? ")
result_2 = 0
if question_2.lower().strip()=="yes":
    result_2 = 0.2

question_3 = input("Are you trading in the same direction as the 50 day moving average? ")
result_3 = 0
if question_3.lower().strip()=="yes":
    result_3 = 0.2

total = result_1 + result_2 + result_3
print(total)
```

The main issue was that you were just printing the result values and not storing the result in a variable and in total you were printing only the content of question_x (the user's input).

I solved this issue also removing the else pre_setting the value of result_x to 0.

As added thing I used .lower() (to make the text small caps) and .strip() (to remove the extra spaces in the beginning / end) to make sure that if the user inserts spaces or is using YES / Yes / etc it will work in any case.

Please also try to use [Python style guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) when you write variable names, it will make your code more readable by others and more Pythonic.

Comment: Thank you very much for the assistance. I will definately work my way through the Python style guide.